# Classifying "nice" topological spaces on (occasionally pathological) sets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, separation-axioms

**Background**:

By a *unique convergence* (UC) topology, I mean a topology under which sequences converge to at most one point.

Suppose we are given a set $X$ and a topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$. It can be readily shown that each of the following implies the next:

> (1) $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology on $X$.
>
> (2) $\mathcal T$ is a Hausdorff topology on $X$.
>
> (3) $\mathcal T$ is a UC topology on $X$.
>
> (4) $\mathcal T$ is a T$_1$ topology on $X$.

Moreover, (4) $\implies$ (3) if and only if $X$ is Dedekind-finite; (3) $\implies$ (1) if and only if $X$ is finite.

I've also shown the following:

> Suppose that $X$ is an amorphous set, $\mathcal T$ a Hausdorff topology on $X$, $C:=\bigl\{x\in X:\{x\}\in\mathcal T\bigr\}$ the set of $\mathcal T$-clopen points of $X$. Then $C$ is cofinite in $X$, and putting $n=|X\setminus C|,$ the following are equivalent:
>
> > (a) $n\ne 0.$
> >
> > (b) $\langle X,\mathcal T\rangle$ is compact; in particular, an $n$-point compactification of the discrete space on $C$.
> >
> > (c) $\mathcal T$ is not the discrete topology on $X$.

From this, we see that for amorphous $X$, (2) need not imply (1)--so, unless there *aren't* any amorphous sets, it follows that D-finiteness need not be sufficient for (2) $\implies$ (1).

Finally, if $X$ is uncountable, then the cocountable topology on $X$ shows that (3) need not imply (2).

---

**The Question**: I intend to play more in the realm between (1) and (2) later (*e.g.*: regular Hausdorff, normal Hausdorff). At the moment, though, I'd like to refine what I have already as far as possible. Specifically, I'm curious about the following:

- Is it known to be true that (3) $\implies$ (2) if and only if $X$ is finite? If so, does anyone know of a non-Hausdorff UC topology on a countably infinite set?
- Is there known to be an equivalent condition on the cardinality of $X$ so that (2) $\implies$ (1)?

Comment: Why have you crossed it to MO? One site is enough for starters. You should know this by now.

Comment: Generally, pick one. Wait a week or so, and if no answer was given, go for the other. "One" usually indicates MSE, "the other" MO. Although in rare cases, the other way around.

Comment: Other post deleted. Link removed. I will avoid immediate dual posts in the future. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: In a Hausdorff space we have a slightly stronger property: Each convergent sequence has only one cluster point, not just a unique limit. On the other hand, if each cluster point is the limit of a subsequence, then it is equivalent to UC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, the one-point compactification of the rationals is $KC$ (compact sets are closed) and hence $UC$, but it’s not Hausdorff.

**Added:** For the second question, suppose that $X$ is infinite. Fix $p\in X$, let $$\mathscr{B}=\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\setminus\{p\}\big\}\cup\big\{X\setminus F:F\subseteq X\setminus\{p\}\text{ is finite}\big\}\;,$$ and let $\tau$ be the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$. Clearly $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a Hausdorff space, and it’s not discrete. Thus, (2) implies (1) only for finite spaces.

Comment: (+1) Nice! Looks like I'll need to add KC spaces to my queue of study.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't believe that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, as written. It looks like you meant to to topologize $X$ as the one-point compactification of the discrete space on $X\setminus\{p\},$ which certainly works as a counterexample, and I can't believe I didn't think of it!

Comment: I guess you just posted a topological base, by accident.

Comment: @Cameron: Yep: mental short circuit from base to topology. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks again, Brian. I'll look around in the spaces between (3) and (2), (2) and (1), and see what I can see.

Comment: @Cameron: My pleasure; it was something a little different.